# jQuery getting input of multiple select element gives me output of wrong element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, menu

I'm having trouble with getting the input of an < select > tag.

I figured out this jQuery snippet but something is wrong... If you run the snippet you can see that it is always just outputting the value of the first < select > element and not correctly outputting the option of the other < select > elements...

// Try the second element.

```js
$("#ONE").on('change', function(eve) {
  console.log($(this).children("option:selected").prop("value"));
  var valueTWO = $("option:selected").prop("value");
});

$("#TWO").on('change', function(eve) {
  console.log($(this).children("option:selected").prop("value"));
  var valueONE = $("option:selected").prop("value");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    <select name="" id="ONE">
      <option title="A">A</option>
      <option title="B">B</option>
    </select>
    <!-- End td 1 -->
  </td>
  <td>
    <select class="" id='TWO' name="">
      <option value="C">C</option>
      <option value="D">D</option>
      <option value="E">E</option>
      <option value="F">F</option>
    </select>
    <!-- End td 2 -->
  </td>
  <td>
```

Comment: EDIT: Improved the snippet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your  `$("option:selected")` selector is not being limited to only the changed dropdown - it's saying "Select **all** selected options on the entire page", and because there are multiple, it returns the first.

Try doing this instead:

```
$(this).children("option:selected").prop("value")
```

By doing `$(this).children`, you've narrowed down your selector to look only at options within the changed dropdown.

That being said, you can do a `.val()` on a dropdown/select to get the value, instead of having to traverse through selected options:

```
$('#mySelect').change(function() {
    console.log( $(this).val() );
}
```